# Cannot create Asp.Net application in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to build a Asp.Net application with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate for the first time so I am not sure do I need something else installed to do this ? Because everytime I select `Asp.Net MVC 3 Web Application` I always get on error, that the current instalion doesn't support this.

My Only options from menu are:

```
Asp.Net MVC 3 Web Application
Ajax Control Extender
AjaxServerControl
ASP.NET Server Control
```

PS: I also installed Web Platform.

Comment: Exactly when do you get the error and exactly what does the error say?

Comment: I get the error when I choose New Project-> Asp.Net MVC 3 Web App-> Internet Application or Empty Project, and it says that the project cannot be oppened and it is not supported by the current instalion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install the Visual Web Developer component when you installed Visual Studio?

Comment: The OP said he is using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. This has everything installed. It's probably ASP.NET MVC 3 corrupted installation.

Comment: With ultimate you have the *option* of installing everything. But you can definitely skip VWD, it is an option. I'd bet on corruption as well.

Comment: I don't remember if I deselected something in the options when installing, but I will reinstall it again and see what happends

Comment: Yep, I didn't have Visual Web Developer Installed